# Check all values in range match criteria based on string index criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to check that **all** instances of the value in the blue table `Index` column have a corresponding value of `YES`, and report this data into the green table.

[image]

**My attempted solution**
I *think* I have a solution... but surely there is something better than this janky method!

```
={SUM((Table1[INDEX]=[@INDEX])*(Table1[VALUE]="YES"))=COUNTIF(Table1[INDEX],Table2[@])}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula under your "PASS" column in green table:

`=IF((COUNTIF(A:A,D2))=COUNTIFS(B:B,"YES",A:A,D2),"YES","NO")`

**Note:**
Change the column value regarding your column (based on your excel). The above formula is written for your table considering your BLUE table is Column A, B -- empty column C -- GREEN table is Column D, E

Comment: thank you, I think this runs a bit faster than my method.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just count "No" rather than "Yes", which simplifies the formula:

`=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,D1,B:B,"NO")>0,"NO","YES")`

Comment: Did you mean =IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,"NO")>0,"NO","YES")